# Word Online - does not display change tracking in color?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, office365

I was emailed two word docs.

Fine.

I used local Word, with change tracking turned on, and made several important changes and additions.

I sent the modified docs back to my colleague.

OK so far.

But now I see, in Outlook Online, that when I click on the attachments there, they open in Word Online... and my changes are not in color. They look like plain text.

IOW, someone might look at these docs and **not know that I have changed them**.

(How can Word hide this crucial (and expected) information?)

**I understand** that Word Online does not support tracked changes... so **why does it open the document?** Shouldn't it simply tell me "This document contains information that Word Online cannot display, please open this document in Word."

**The question**: How do I use Outlook Online and **avoid falling into this trap?**

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I use Outlook Online and avoid falling into this trap?

> in Outlook Online, that when I click on the attachments there, they open in Word Online... and my changes are not in color. They look like plain text.

Word Online does not support Tracking Changes:

> [image]

Source [Compare Word features on different platforms - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-Word-features-on-different-platforms-5e00dfba-3d7c-4222-b850-a0527ff7b066?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bm2)

---

#### So what can I do if I can't see the changes?

> You can’t see tracked changes in Word Online but they’re still there. When you open a document in Word Online that has tracked
>   changes, they’re preserved and any changes you make will also be
>   tracked. You just won’t see them until you open the document in the
>   Word desktop application.
>
> - You can’t turn Track Changes on or off in Word Online; you can only do that the Word desktop application.
> - You’ll know Track Changes is on when you see it in the status bar at the bottom of Word Online.
>
>   [image: track changes status]
>
> Word Online also lets you [add, view, and delete comments](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/insert-comments-in-a-document-95a93b1e-aaea-4c8d-a25d-8f91eb217390), as well as
>   reply to comments from other reviewers.
>
> If you have the Word desktop application, use the Open in Word command
>   to open the document and turn on track changes. When you’re done and
>   you save the document, it will continue to be stored where you opened
>   it in Word Online. Tracked changes will be preserved and—if you turned
>   on Track Changes before you opened the document in Word Online—any
>   changes you make in Word Online will also be tracked.

Source [Can I use Track Changes in Word Online? - Word](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/can-i-use-track-changes-in-word-online-9016b7f8-b864-458f-ba45-183049f90bd8)

Comment: "You can’t see tracked changes in Word Online but they’re still there. "  IOW: Word Online is hiding critical information that is present in the document, without warning the user that they are only seeing part of the story. Does this mean that Word Online should not be used for contracts, or documents affect company revenue?

Comment: @SamJones No idea, I'm a techie not a lawyer :) But see the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: That is cool! I am not asking for legal advice. I am trying to understand how to use Outlook Online without falling in the trap of viewing Word attachments on line, that have important data being hidden from me.

Comment: OP enhanced to incorporate some of the material from this response.

Comment: "use the Open in Word command" ...

Comment: Open in Word is not the answer. I know I can download the file in Word. The issue is that when I preview in Outlook, everything looks fine. I don't want to download the file (I will if I must, but really don't want to for everything). The question is how to avoid the situation of Outlook Online/Word Online showing me a document that has hidden information that I do not know is present!

Comment: "Shouldn't it simply tell me "This document contains information that Word Online cannot display, please open this document in Word." well it doesn't. You should report that to MS as a bug/feature request.